# Babel @babel/plugin-transform-runtime - Use in the browser

Tags: javascript, json, babeljs

I am confused about the use Babel plugin `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` in the browser.

This is my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "esmodules": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "absoluteRuntime": false,
        "corejs": false,
        "helpers": true,
        "regenerator": true,
        "useESModules": true,
        "version": "7.9.6"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

This is the `main.js` code I get transpiled in my `dist` folder

```
import _asyncToGenerator from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator";
import header from './components/header.js';
import user from './components/user.js';

var app = /*#__PURE__*/function () {
  var _ref = _asyncToGenerator(function* () {
    document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = header();
    document.getElementById('user').innerHTML = yield user();
  });

  return function app() {
    return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}(); // init app

app();
```

And I see the above code is not prepared to run in the browser straightaway. So I have to change the first line manually like this:

```
import _asyncToGenerator from './components/asyncToGenerator.js'
```

And of course I have to manually copy `asyncToGenerator.js` from `node_modules` to my corresponding project folder.

Is there a way to run Babel and get this esm file in my components folder automatically? Am I missing something in the way `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` plugin is used?